# How to databind a local variable in an ASPX template?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, data-binding

I have a UserControl named `SlidingScaleTableReadonly` with a bindable public member `ScaleEntries`, which take a List of struct instances. In the parent page, these lists are stored in a dictionary (`InsulinSlidingScaleProtocolEntries`), and I must render one `SlidingScaleTableReadonly` for each entry in this dictionary. Here's my template code so far:

```xml
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="SlidingScaleTableReadonly"  Src="~/Patient/SlidingScaleTableReadonly.ascx" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="phContent" runat="server">
    <h1>Échelles</h1>
    <% For Each drug In InsulinSlidingScaleProtocolEntries %>
        <h2><%= drug.Key %></h2>
        <uc:SlidingScaleTableReadonly runat="server" ScaleEntries="<%# drug.Value %>" />
    <% Next %>
</asp:Content>
```

My problem is at line 7:

> BC30451 'drug' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

If I replace `drug.Value` with a property available in code behind, the new variable can be found. I'm guessing it's not possible to directly data-bind local variables in ASPX? If that's the case, how can I use data-binding inside an iteration?

## Edit - Changing the provenance of the bound value

I've changed the code a bit. Right after the "For Each" loop opening, a code-behind property named `CurrentDrug` is reassigned with the value of `drug.Value`, and `uc:SlidingScaleTableReadonly` get it's `ScaleEntry` from that new property. But that doesn't work either, the reassignment won't do shuck and `ScaleEntry` is always `Nothing` (or whatever initial value I gave to `CurrentDrug`).

Here's the new template:

```xml
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="SlidingScaleTableReadonly"  Src="~/Patient/SlidingScaleTableReadonly.ascx" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="phContent" runat="server">
    <h1>Échelles</h1>
    <% For Each drug In InsulinSlidingScaleProtocolEntries
        CurrentDrug = drug.Value %>
        <h2><%= drug.Key %></h2>
        <uc:SlidingScaleTableReadonly runat="server" ScaleEntries="<%# CurrentDrug  %>" />
    <% Next %>
</asp:Content>
```

And code-behind:

```vb
Public CurrentDrug As List(Of ScaleEntry)

Public Property InsulinSlidingScaleProtocolEntries As Dictionary(Of String, List(Of ScaleEntry))
    '...
End Property
```

## Edit - (Not) a solution: Stopped using aspx templates

I have to move on, and it seems like I'm not going to do any progress with aspx templates. I've rewritten the page so the UserControl is declared and inserted in code-behind. I think that's not how one should build an interface, that's not where that kind of logic should be place but I really want to move on.

Here's the new template code:

```xml
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="phContent" runat="server">
    <h1>Échelles</h1>
    <div id="scaleContainer" runat="server"></div>
</asp:Content>
```

Code-behind:

```vb
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    For Each prescription In InsulinSlidingScaleProtocolEntries
        Dim label As New HtmlGenericControl("h2") With {
            .InnerText = prescription.Key
        }

        Dim table = CType(Page.LoadControl("~/Patient/SlidingScaleTableReadonly.ascx"), SlidingScaleTableReadonly)
        table.ScaleEntries = prescription.Value

        scaleContainer.Controls.Add(label)
        scaleContainer.Controls.Add(table)
    Next
End Sub
```

If you have a better solution, I'll be happy to see it.

Comment: %# is ONLY for the data bound/binding event and to get at the data from the datasource + databind event, . you can try <%  %> just like you have for your other code.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Doing so throws the following error: `Cannot create an object of type '(...)' from its string representation '<% drug.Value %>' for the 'ScaleEntries' property.` I want to pass a list of object, not a string.